# Round javascript string and display dollar format with no decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

The server provides JSON containing a **string** such as `1234567.89`.

How do I convert it to `$ 1,234,568`?

Based on [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript), I can convert it to `$ 1,234,567.89`.

```
return "$ " + parseFloat(n).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
```

While not perfect because it rounds down versus rounds to nearest dollar, I would have thought the following would work, but it does not:

```
return "$ " + parseFloat(n).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
```

I also unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
return "$ " + Math.round(parseFloat(n)).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function roundToDollars(n) { 
    return "$ " + 
        parseFloat(n).toFixed(0)
            .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1,"); 
}
```

Note that I don't think the function you're asking for is a good idea:

- you're using (imprecise) floats for decimal arithmetic.
- and your input here - "n" - is a string, when it really isn't a string.
- it sounds to me like the "format number" and "prepend $" and "round to nearest" bits are all orthogonal, and a cleaner API wouldn't stick this in one function.

Incidentally, all I changed from your example was the "terminator" detection - since the amount is be rounded, I'm not looking for a dot (`\.`), but simply the end of the string (`$`).  To be compatible with both, you could use the regex `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\.|$))/g`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function formatNumber(val){

    val = Math.round(parseFloat(val));
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }

    return '$ ' + val;

}

alert(formatNumber(1234567.89));
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dybg5ye1/2/

**Edit**: forgot the dollar sign :)

Comment: Thanks foxygen.  What is the purpose of the while statement?

Comment: It allows us to iterate through the string, looking for at least one digit followed by 3 numbers, and if found, a comma is inserted and the value is updated. Once this condition is no longer met - the loop exits and the formatted value is returned